# Can I cancel a mission I started in Tiny Tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

In Tiny Tower, there are multiple missions available.  I accidentally accepted a mission without having both type of stores built.  I only have one, and it is deducting ~1k stock every time I restock that store.

Can I cancel this mission so it doesn't remove those stocked items until I am really ready for it?
[image: TT]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you switch to/select a different mission, it will cancel the mission you are currently doing.

Other than that, there is no way to just cancel the mission and not start another (other than finishing it).

Comment: Fastest. Answer. Ever. Also, I just tried it - worked perfectly! Thank you !  +1 (in 7 hours when my CD pops, and Check )